# jQuery UI tabs load event sometimes seems to fire too early

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

This is a weird one. I have a set of jQuery UI tabs, which are loaded via AJAX. The load event, which is supposed to fire once the content of the tab is loaded and ready, sometimes fires after the height of the content is calculated and sometimes before.

Here's the situation: the first tab contains two `.resizable()` divs - there's a center line that you can drag left or right to make one or the other panel larger. The only way that I could get them to work was to position them absolutely.

The problem is that, because they're positioned absolutely, the containing div can't automatically adjust to their height. To make them fit inside, I have to first find their height (the content is dynamic, so the height could change), then tell the containing div to be 70 pixels taller than that height. It's a simple function:

```
function setTabHeight() {
    // The problem is only with Tab1, because of the absolute positioning. Any other tab, height can be set automatically.
    if ($("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active') != 0) { $("#tabs").height('auto'); return false; }
    // Tab1 contains two side-by-side divs, which we'll call "east" and "west".
    // This figures out which is taller and makes the containing div taller than that.
    var westDiv = $("#westDiv").height();
    var eastDiv = $("#eastDiv").height();
    if (westDiv > eastDiv) { $("#tabs").height(westDiv + 70); }
    else { $("#tabs").height(eastDiv + 70);
}
```

I call that function like so:

```
$(#tabs).tabs({
    load: function (e, ui) {
        [a bunch of other code, mostly the call to .resizable()]
        setTabHeight();
    }
});
```

Except that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I can sit there reloading the exact same information and sometimes it'll adjust the containing div and sometimes it won't. I put `console.log($('#westDiv').height())` at the end of my load function, and again, sometimes it knows the height of the div, sometimes it thinks its height is zero.

The only conclusion I can come to is that the load event for jQuery UI tabs fires just a bit faster than the height of the div inside can be calculated. I can make it work by using `setTimeout(setTabHeight, 10)`, but that seems pretty spectacularly kludgy, and I'm worried that a user on a slower computer might still have trouble if my arbitrary number of ten milliseconds turns out to be wrong.

Any thoughts for a more general solution - specifically, a way to fire the function *only after* the height of the elements has been calculated?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could solve this using [jQuery.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Something like this:

```
function getDivHeight(strDivId) {
    var def = $.Deferred(), $div = $("#" + strDivId);

    setInterval(function () {
        var intDivHeight = $div.height();

        if (intDivHeight > 0) {
            def.resolve(intDivHeight);
        }
    }, 40);

    return def.promise();
}


$.when(getDivHeight("westDiv")).then(function (divHeight) {
    // Do something with the westDiv's height here.
});
```

It's not much and you need some extra logic to make it work for your specific situation but I think this might be the right direction for you to make a working solution.